# TFS-2017 - Add a step to enter Username and password

Tags: powershell, tfs, parameters, arguments, powershell-4.0

I have a build that creates .zip package and projectName.SetParameters.xml i want to overide the parameters in The projectName.SetParameters.xml file with my script

I have a powershell script with Mandotary parameters, I want the user to input their username and password before they can deploy to IIS in TFS i was following this guide [link](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/webdeploy-configs-and-web-release-management)
UPDATE: The REalese build works but it doesn't ask the user to input the username and password, Do i have to set them manually inside the argument box on the Powershell step?

In my TFS I Have a powershell step i added the argument -paramsFilePath C:/somepath/.../.../projectName.SetParameters.xml

```
param(
    [string]$paramsFilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$username,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $password
)
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Entering script setParameters.ps1"
Write-Verbose -Verbose ("Path to Parameters: {0}" -f $paramsFilePath)

# get the environment variables
$vars = Get-ChildItem -path env:*

# read in the setParameters file
$contents = Get-Content -Path $paramsFilePath

# perform a regex replacement
$newContents = "";
$contents | % {
    $line = $_
    if ($_ -match "__Username__") {
        $setting = Get-ChildItem -path env:* | ? { $_.Name -eq $Matches[1]  }
        if ($setting) {
            Write-Verbose -Verbose ("Replacing key {0} with value from environment" -f $username.Name)
            $line = $_ -replace "__Username__", $username.Value
        }
    }
    $newContents = $line 
}

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Overwriting SetParameters file with new values"
Set-Content $paramsFilePath -Value $newContents

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Exiting script setParameters.ps1"
```

Here is my Parameters.xml code

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?-->
 <parameters>
    <parameter name="machineURL" description="Please enter the name of the Environment" defaultvalue="_UrlValue_" tags="">
      <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='machineURL']/@value">
      </parameterentry>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="username" description="Please enter the username" defaultvalue="__UserName__" tags="">
       <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='username']/@value">
       </parameterentry>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="password" description="Please enter the password" defaultvalue="__Password__" tags="">
       <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='password']/@value">
       </parameterentry>
    </parameter>
    </parameters>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell execution in TFS Build and Release is only in non-interactive mode possible. The build and release process will only streams the execution result to the build console.

> You have to create a variable with the username. For the password you should use hidden variable:

[image]

> Yes you have to place the arguments inside the argument box of the
>   PowerShell step

[image]

Note: The password field seems secure and not readable but it is not really hard to read the content of a hidden variable.

Create the variables and set the values. After that you can use this command line parameter in the PowerShell step argument box.

```
-paramsFilePath $(paramsFilePath) -username $(username) -password $(password)
```

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error now `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'username`

Comment: Did you created the variable in your Release Definition?

Comment: Yes i got it sorted, but i have another issue everything seems to work but in my setParameters.xml file it only catches the first parameter `<parameter name="machineURL" ...` is my syntax correct for passing multiple paramaters?

Comment: The result of your snippet is a broken xml file. Change $newContents = $line to $newContents += $line

Comment: That´s a new topic. Can you create a separated question for this?

Comment: I have a solution for it. Give me a trigger.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241083/pubxml-change-variables-with-release-definition-variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145374/discussion-between-wojtek-t-and-k7s5a).