# .pubxml - Change variables with Release Definition variables

Tags: xml, powershell, parameters, arguments

I am trying to run my powershell script i pass in all the arguments everything is working but my setParameters.xml file in not changing the Variables from the Realese definition instead it keeps the values from my Release.pubxml file. How could I modify my .pubxml file to have variable/parameters i could change using powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring all parameters which you wont to replace in this form **ParamToReplace**
Create a environment variable ParamToReplace

```
# read the setParameters.xml file
$contents = Get-Content -Path $paramsFilePath

# Replease all environment variables with mathing token
Get-ChildItem -path env:* | % {$contents = $contents -replace ('__{0}__' -f $_.Name),$_.Value}

# save the new content of the setParameters.xml
Set-Content $paramsFilePath  -Value $contents
```

Comment: Ahh, i get now, this should work fine, i just need to sort out my Release.pubxml file and it should work!